# lhs Unit Eigenvectors in Python for DeGroot model Convergence for Social Networking problems

Tags: python, social-network

The influence array at time 0 is:

```
1/3, 1/3 1/3
1/2, 1/2, 0
0, 0.25, 0.75
```

It is suppose to converge to the array:

```
3/11 4/11 4/11
3/11 4/11 4/11
3/11 4/11 4/11
```

You are suppose to be able to get the convergence array by taking the left hand side (lhs) unit vector of the array at time 0.

My linear algebra can be rusty at times and I want to try this in python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eig
np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
limT = np.array([(0.33,0.33,0.33),(0.5,0.5,0.0),(0.0,0.25,0.75)])
w, vl, vr = eig(limT, left=True)
lhs = vl.conj().T.dot(limT)
>>> lhs
array([[-0.0678,  0.0335,  0.0335],
       [-0.4669, -0.6231, -0.6231],
       [-0.2958, -0.1006,  0.3904]])
lhs/np.linalg.det(lhs)
array([[ -2.385 ,   1.1795,   1.1795],
       [-16.4266, -21.9221, -21.9221],
       [-10.4052,  -3.5378,  13.7349]])
```

The final array is obviously not:

```
3/11 4/11 4/11
3/11 4/11 4/11
3/11 4/11 4/11
```

I could have misunderstood several issues and appreciate the assistance.

Comment: What is `T` in this code?  Could you explain what you are trying to calculate in English or math, given that your code is obviously not working anyway?

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer, if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much, if anything, about the DeGroot model, but using an analogy to Markov chains, you get the long-run convergence through the matrix exponential. So there's two issues. 1) The existence of the eigenvector for an eigenvalue of 1 is just a necessary condition that the limit exists. 2) You shouldn't round off your probabilities. The first row doesn't sum to 1 (or close enough in floating point) and this matters.

```
[~/]
[1]: limT = np.array([(1/3.,1/3.,1/3.),(0.5,0.5,0.0),(0.0,0.25,0.75)])

[~/]
[2]: np.linalg.matrix_power(limT, 10)
[2]: 
array([[ 0.27272727,  0.36363636,  0.36363636],
    [ 0.27331321,  0.36383168,  0.36285511],
    [ 0.27214134,  0.36344105,  0.36441761]])

[~/]
[3]: np.linalg.matrix_power(limT, 25)
[3]: 
array([[ 0.27272727,  0.36363636,  0.36363636],
    [ 0.27272729,  0.36363637,  0.36363634],
    [ 0.27272725,  0.36363636,  0.36363639]])

[~/]
[4]: np.linalg.matrix_power(limT, 50)
[4]: 
array([[ 0.27272727,  0.36363636,  0.36363636],
    [ 0.27272727,  0.36363636,  0.36363636],
    [ 0.27272727,  0.36363636,  0.36363636]])
```

If you want the unique stationary distribution vector for a Markov chain, you can use the eigenvector associated with the unit eigenvalue. Just looking at the wiki for DeGroot Learning, I think this is analogous to consensus beliefs.

```
[~/]
[5]: from scipy import linalg

[~/]
[6]: eig, vl, vr = linalg.eig(limT, left=True)

[~/]
[7]: idx = np.argmin(np.abs(1 - eig))

[~/]
[8]: s = vl[:,idx]

[~/]
[9]: s /= s.sum()

[~/]
[10]: s
[10]: array([ 0.27272727,  0.36363636,  0.36363636])

[~/]
[11]: np.dot(s, limT)
[11]: array([ 0.27272727,  0.36363636,  0.36363636])
```

Comment: Good catch! (+1) The rounding issue is only part of the problem, however. Because of the rounding, all eigenvalues have absolute values less than $1$.  (The largest is approximately $0.997275$.)  Thus the limiting distribution will be $(0,0,0)$ (but is approached very slowly: even after 1000 iterations the largest e.v. is still around $0.065$). Instead, the O.P.'s code (whatever it might be doing, which is unclear) appears to be *diverging.*

Comment: Indeed. The presence of an eigenvalue equal to 1 is a necessary condition for convergence. When I saw there wasn't convergence I worked backwards to the rounding issue.